# QiskitRuntimeService error - Provided API key could not be found

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to use QiskitRuntimeService() and start a session to find the expectation value of some operator but I keep getting this error:

> ApiException: Error: Provided API key could not be found., Code: 400.

The line that gives me the error is:

```
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your account before you can start using Qiskit Runtime. If you don't have the credentials saved in your disk, you can initialize a `QiskitRuntimeService` instance as follows:

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

# Save an IBM Cloud account on disk
token = '***'  # <== Use your token here
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel="ibm_quantum", token=token)
```

You can find the token in your [IBM Quantum account page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/account).

If the error keeps happening, try to delete the saved account from disk at first then save it again:

```
QiskitRuntimeService.delete_account()
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel="ibm_quantum", token=token, overwrite=True)
```

Once the credentials are saved, you can initialize the `QiskitRuntimeService` instance without passing any parameters:

```
# Read default credentials from disk
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
```

For more details see [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/partners/qiskit_ibm_runtime/how_to/account-management.html).

Comment: I already did that, but it still won't work. I also tried to regenerate my token but I got the same error every time.

Comment: Did you try to add `overwrite=True` when calling with the new token?

Comment: Yes, I did that too.

Comment: I actually get two different error. One of them is the one I mentioned and the other error is:
IBMNotAuthorizedError: '401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/users/loginWithToken. Login failed., Error code: 3446.'

Comment: Try to delete the saved account from disk at first: `QiskitRuntimeService.delete_account()`.

Comment: This worked actually.

Comment: I updated the answer to include this suggestion